# SetInterval не обнуляется

Tags: setinterval, javascript

Весьма удивлен поведением функции setInterval. С помощью $.load  в див подгружается кусок станицы, где есть код:

```
$(function (){
 var id = setInterval(my_function,5000);
}
```

Хорошо, в этот же див загружаем другой контент - setInterval продолжает работать. Почему? Ведь по идее прежняя DOM-структура должна удалиться вместе со скриптом. 
Ладно, добавил строку:

```
$(function (){
  if (typeof id != 'undefined') clearInterval(id);// - вот эту добавил
  var id = setInterval(my_function,5000);
}
```

По барабану - id всегда undefined. И сколько ни подгружай этот контент, столько же и будет инициализироваться Interval с увеличивающимся в 2 раза id, вплоть до закипания процессора. Почему эта функция так себя ведет? И как ее остановить?

Comment: надо чтобы id была определена в той области видимости, которая является общей для этих замыканий. короче говоря вместо `var id=` пишите в данном случае `window.id=`

Comment: @eicto, да, id больше не растет в геометрической прогрессии, хотя console.log(id) показывает, что id каждый раз на 1 больше предыдущего значения. Почему?

Comment: потому-что вместо clearinterval вам надо делать return

Comment: Странно все это, однако все это работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Deus почитайте [здесь](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure#scope)

Comment: @eicto, я думаю, проблема не в том, что я не догоняю, что такое scope, ведь с остальными функциями всегда было все ок. Дело в setInterval. Объявленная внутри любой функции она проявляет себя как глобальный объект, что ли. Это не первый раз, когда я с ней морочаю голову. Действительно, ранее я привязывал ее к переменной в пространстве имен window. Подзабыл. Все равно поведение ее мне не понятно.

Comment: @Deus, setInterval здесь не причем.

И, простите конечно, но что такое scope, вы ни единого раза не понимаете иначе у вас не было бы такого элементарного вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в области видимости. Решение достаточно простое — обьявите переменную в каком-то глобальном "пространстве":

```
var id;

$(function(){
    id=setInterval(my_function,5000);
})

$(function(){
    if(typeof id!='undefined')
        clearInterval(id);
    id=setInterval(my_function,5000);
})
```

Или же, как и сказал `eicto`, используйте `windows.id` вместо `id`.

Comment: или же, что куда лучше, не разбивайте на 2 разные функции инициализацию и очистку интервала.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, у меня не 2 функции. Некорректная формулировка вопроса вышла. Я просто показал как изменил функцию. А насчет scope - вы же согласитесь, что при загрузке нового контента на место прежнего, последний перестает существовать? Вместе с дивами, функциями и, тем более, локальными переменными? Почему этого не проиcходит с функцией setInterval? Старого контента больше не существует, а setInterval продолжает работать.

Comment: @Deus вы меняете только DOM, javascript существует в другой области памяти. в том самом объекте scope про который я говорил.

Comment: @eicto, почему-то я подумал, что вы говорите о scope в общем понимании, как просто о пространстве имен. Признаю свою безграмотность, ибо я и не знал, что существует  целый объект [[scope]]. Разберемся.